# python convert contents of .kv (Kivy) file to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, kivy

I would like to convert "maps.kv" file contents into dictionary.

I have key value files call "maps.kv"

Contents looks like this.

```
"map_info"
{
  "map_A"
  {
    "Map_cooldown"        "100"
    "Map_installed_date"  "1659754646"
  }
  "map_B"
  {
    "Map_cooldown"        "200"
    "Map_installed_date"  "1659754646"
  }
}
```

Above contents without formatting

```
b'"map_info"\n{\n\t"map_A"\n\t{\n\t\t"Map_cooldown"\t\t"100"\n\t\t"Map_installed_date"\t\t"1659754646"\n\t}\n\t"map_B"\n\t{\n\t\t"Map_cooldown"\t\t"200"\n\t\t"Map_installed_date"\t\t"1659754646"\n\t}\n}\n'
```

I want to convert above "contents" to nested dictionary

Desire output

```
dict_contents = { 'map_A': { 'Map_cooldown':100, 'Map_installed_date':'1659754646'},
                  'map_B': { 'Map_cooldown':200, 'Map_installed_date':'1659754646'}}
```

Here is my code so far

```
with open('maps.kv') as f:
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code =>import ast<=:

```
xx=b'"map_info"\n{\n\t"map_A"\n\t{\n\t\t"Map_cooldown"\t\t"100"\n\t\t"Map_installed_date"\t\t"1659754646"\n\t}\n\t"map_B"\n\t{\n\t\t"Map_cooldown"\t\t"200"\n\t\t"Map_installed_date"\t\t"1659754646"\n\t}\n}\n'

    xx1 = [i.replace('\n','') for i in xx.decode('UTF-8').splitlines()][1:]

    ast.literal_eval(','.join(xx1).\
                     replace(',\t','').\
                     replace('\t\t',':').\
                     replace('{\t',':{').\
                     replace('\t',',').\
                     replace('}"','},"').\
                     replace('},}','}}'))
```

Output:

[image]